Computing TCP's checksum from byte array
I have been working at this for a while now without being able to get the correct CheckSum value. Here my method is taking in 3-byte arrays. The first containing the IPv4Header's bytes, the second containing TCPHeader bytes, and lastly the payload. I already verified that these bytes are correct, and I am trying to cross reference as I go along but after so many attempts, I keep coming up short. I have also not found any guide with any actual code that does this from a byte array.
        public override ushort ComputeChecksum(byte[] ipv4Header, byte[] transportHeader, byte[] payload)
        {
            int pseudoHeaderLength = 12; // Pseudo-header is 12 bytes
            int tcpLength = transportHeader.Length;
            int payloadLength = payload.Length;
            int totalLength = pseudoHeaderLength + tcpLength + payloadLength;
            bool isOddLength = (totalLength % 2 != 0);

            byte[] pseudoHeaderAndTcpSegment = new byte[totalLength + (isOddLength ? 1 : 0)];
            Console.WriteLine($"pseudoHeaderLength:{pseudoHeaderLength} transportHeader.Length:{tcpLength} payloadLength:{payloadLength} totalLength:{totalLength} newTotalLength:{pseudoHeaderAndTcpSegment.Length} OddLength:{isOddLength}");

            // Copy Source IP address (4 bytes)
            Buffer.BlockCopy(ipv4Header, 12, pseudoHeaderAndTcpSegment, 0, 4);
            Console.WriteLine((BitConverter.ToString(pseudoHeaderAndTcpSegment).Replace("-", " ") + ", "));
            Console.WriteLine("");

            // Copy Destination IP address (4 bytes)
            Buffer.BlockCopy(ipv4Header, 16, pseudoHeaderAndTcpSegment, 4, 4);
            Console.WriteLine((BitConverter.ToString(pseudoHeaderAndTcpSegment).Replace("-", " ") + ", "));
            Console.WriteLine("");

            // Zero byte (1 byte)
            pseudoHeaderAndTcpSegment[8] = 0;

            // Protocol (1 byte)
            pseudoHeaderAndTcpSegment[9] = ipv4Header[9];
            Console.WriteLine((BitConverter.ToString(pseudoHeaderAndTcpSegment).Replace("-", " ") + ", ") + " Protocol:" + ipv4Header[9]); // ipv4Header[9] prints 6 like it should
            Console.WriteLine("");

            // TCP length (2 bytes)
            pseudoHeaderAndTcpSegment[10] = (byte)((tcpLength + payloadLength) >> 8); // try <<
            pseudoHeaderAndTcpSegment[11] = (byte)(tcpLength & 0xFF);
            Console.WriteLine((BitConverter.ToString(pseudoHeaderAndTcpSegment).Replace("-", " ") + ", "));
            Console.WriteLine("");

            // Make a copy of the transport header to zero out the checksum
            byte[] transportHeaderCopy = new byte[tcpLength];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(transportHeader, 0, transportHeaderCopy, 0, tcpLength);
            transportHeaderCopy[16] = 0; // Zero out the checksum field (16th byte)
            transportHeaderCopy[17] = 0; // Zero out the checksum field (17th byte)
            Console.WriteLine((BitConverter.ToString(transportHeaderCopy).Replace("-", " ") + ", "));
            Console.WriteLine("");

            // Copy the modified TCP header with zeroed checksum field
            Buffer.BlockCopy(transportHeaderCopy, 0, pseudoHeaderAndTcpSegment, 12, tcpLength);
            Console.WriteLine("TCPHeader:" + (BitConverter.ToString(pseudoHeaderAndTcpSegment).Replace("-", " ") + ", "));
            Console.WriteLine("");

            // Copy the payload
            Buffer.BlockCopy(payload, 0, pseudoHeaderAndTcpSegment, 12 + tcpLength, payload.Length);
            if (isOddLength)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Odd Length adding a zero");
                pseudoHeaderAndTcpSegment[totalLength] = 0;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Payload:" + (BitConverter.ToString(pseudoHeaderAndTcpSegment).Replace("-", " ") + ", "));
            Console.WriteLine("");

            return ComputeChecksum(pseudoHeaderAndTcpSegment);
        }

        protected static ushort ComputeChecksum(byte[] data)
        {
            int length = data.Length;
            int i = 0;
            long sum = 0;

            while (length > 1)
            {
                sum += BinaryPrimitives.ReadUInt16BigEndian(data.AsSpan(i, 2));

                i += 2;
                length -= 2;
            }

            if (length > 0)
            {
                sum += data[i] << 8;
            }

            while ((sum >> 16) != 0)
            {
                sum = (sum & 0xFFFF) + (sum >> 16);
            }

            return (ushort)(~sum);
        }


The bytes that get printed seem to be correct and I read this article calculation-of-tcp-checksum which told me the that I should go Source IP, Destination IP, Segment Length, Protocol, fixed 8 bits followed up by the TCP header and the payload. So, I think my order is correct although I am not sure if I did the fixed 8 bits and the Length part correctly. I am also not sure if I am calculating the actual 2 byte answer correctly using ones complement. Any corrections would be greatly appreciated thank you!
Edit: I thought I might also add in the debug messages in case anyone finds it useful
A2 9F 82 EA 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00,

A2 9F 82 EA C0 A8 32 86 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00,

A2 9F 82 EA C0 A8 32 86 00 42 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00,

A2 9F 82 EA C0 A8 32 86 00 42 06 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00,  Protocol:6

A2 9F 82 EA C0 A8 32 86 00 42 06 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00,

A2 9F 82 EA C0 A8 32 86 00 42 06 00 01 BB F0 49 FD 02 5E BB 35 90 17 70 50 18 00 04 83 57 00 00 17 03 03 00 29 E0 63 19 68 7C 3F 19 3F 33 A6 9E 0B CD 54 47 8A 97 1B CC 97 1A 45 CD 5C EF 75 3E 75 A0 32 A3 46 2D 3F FD 37 DC F3 DB 34 AF,

CorrectCheckSumCheck:22403 0x8357  OurCheck:64005 0x05FA 

The endianness is kina of a pain since the original ushort of our checksum is 22403 and since C# on Windows uses little endian, I needed to convert it to big endian before then displaying it as hex which gives 0x8357 aka the correct value (I know its correct since it matches what I see in the packets full byte array). Then for ours I printed both and its so far off that it's obvious it's not an endianness issue. For context here is the byte array of the TCP header unmodified 01 BB F0 49 FD 02 5E BB 35 90 17 70 50 18 00 04 83 57 00 00

Is this just for learning, or do you have some practical use for this?

@JonasH Well, I am learning about the different protocols, and I normally like to learn things by doing projects rather than just reading about it and pretending like I know it. So, I made a basic C# app that intercepts packets, and right now I am trying to validate headers to detected corrupted packets. I already made a header parser for IPv4, TCP, UDP, and ICMP and this was the next logical step in my learning journey. Its the same way I learned about the PE format by making binary parser for exe's, dll's, and sys files. I also made that project parse PNG files as well which was kinda cool.

Don't forget the checksum field needs to be zero - when you're verifying a captured TCP packet, you need to zero it out.

@Luaan Are you talking about when I copy the TCP headers byte array to my new array, I need to first edit the TCP headers array and zero its checksum and then copy it? That would make sense considering it would not be known yet.

Yeah. And assuming you're using the captured header, you're reading the words wrong - they are big endian, but you're reading them as little endian. I'd recommend using BinaryPrimitives.ReadUInt16BigEndian(data.AsSpan(index, 2)) instead.

@Luaan I will make those changes but I dont think the Endianess is wrong because its printing the bytes from the array in the correct order (the byte arrays were all printed and stored in big endian). Unless BinaryPrimitives.ReadUInt16BigEndian(data.AsSpan(index, 2)) is in reference to something else other than the print statements. I also made those changes but I still am getting the wrong checksum.

@UnSure It's about computing the sum in the ComputeChecksum method. The data is supposed to be added as a sequence of 16-bit words in big endian order; you're adding them as a sequence of 16-bit words in little endian order (except for the odd one, if any, which happens to work out due to the way the padding is supposed to be done).

Here is a working version in LINQPad including two sample headers.
Two very important things to note: words must be read in big endian (network order), and the checksum in the header must be zeroed out if you're verifying captured headers.
void Main()
{
    var pseudoHeader =
        CreatePseudoHeader
        (
            new byte[] { 0xac, 0x18, 0x0b, 0x9f },
            new byte[] { 0xac, 0x18, 0x7e, 0x34 },
            6,
            FromHex("0d3df160ea5e5c54e0e45e585018fa0000000000170303002e0000000000002015cd7f0a9400f87f031162f4de4118d5670f885cea116c630a416883d8569bedc94f2df41d5e20")
        );


    ComputeChecksum(pseudoHeader).ToString("X4").Dump();

    pseudoHeader =
            CreatePseudoHeader
            (
                new byte[] { 0xac, 0x18, 0x7e, 0x34 },
                new byte[] { 0xac, 0x18, 0x0b, 0x9f },
                6,
                FromHex("f1600d3de0e45e58ea5e5c875010101100000000")
            );


    ComputeChecksum(pseudoHeader).ToString("X4").Dump();
}

private static byte[] FromHex(string v)
{
    var buffer = new byte[v.Length / 2];

    for (var i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++)
    {
        buffer[i] = Convert.ToByte(v.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16);
    }

    return buffer;
}

public static ushort ComputeChecksum(byte[] data)
{
    int length = data.Length;
    int i = 0;
    long sum = 0;

    while (length > 1)
    {
        sum += BinaryPrimitives.ReadUInt16BigEndian(data.AsSpan(i, 2));

        i += 2;
        length -= 2;
    }

    if (length > 0)
    {
        sum += data[i] << 8;
    }

    while ((sum >> 16) != 0)
    {
        sum = (sum & 0xFFFF) + (sum >> 16);
    }

    return (ushort)(~sum);
}

public byte[] CreatePseudoHeader(byte[] sourceIp, byte[] destIp, byte protocol, byte[] tcpHeader)
{
    var tcpLength = tcpHeader.Length;
    var pseudoHeader = new byte[12 + tcpLength];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(sourceIp, 0, pseudoHeader, 0, 4);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(destIp, 0, pseudoHeader, 4, 4);
    pseudoHeader[8] = 0;
    pseudoHeader[9] = protocol;
    pseudoHeader[10] = (byte)(tcpLength >> 8);
    pseudoHeader[11] = (byte)(tcpLength & 0xff);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(tcpHeader, 0, pseudoHeader, 12, tcpLength);

    return pseudoHeader;
}

Of course, this is a very straightforward implementation; good enough for learning purposes, but certainly not for any real use :)

Why is your length bellow the protocol was that article I linked incorrect? Also why did you not copy the payload?

@UnSure I went straight from the RFC for TCP; length is after protocol in the header, so that's the order it's computed in. It shouldn't matter, though, since we're just doing addition :)

Wow that actually worked you are amazing!! I also just looked up the RFC and I see this massive article I will for sure need to read it thanks for all your help!

It turns out this does not work for me. For some reason I only get the correct checksum some of the time and I have no idea why. For example, a source of 192.168.50.1 and a destination ip of 192.168.50.134 works (its an inbound packet) but for its outbound version which has the inverse ip's aka a source of 192.168.50.134 and a destination of 192.168.50.1 it fails. I updated my question with my current code. Also I know you mentioned a possible endianness issue but I dont see how that is the case since I am reading the bytes directly from the packets byte buffer.

Endianness is always a problem if you overflow the individual octets. Adding BB00 + BB00 and 00BB + 00BB will give different results. If there is no overflow, you're not going to notice your endianness is wrong. Again, the point isn't what's in the buffer, but how you do the addition - you need to interpret the bytes in the buffer correctly for that - if they're big endian, you need to add them as big endian; if they're little endian, you need to add them as little endian. TCP uses big endian (network order), that's what's in your buffer; your code uses little endian.

But where am I adding them up wrong because the byte arrays should all be in big endian form. I assume you must be referring to the ones compliment method since the other method does not do any addition it just copies arrays around. It makes sense that C# natively uses little endian for its calculations but how do I fix the ComputeChecksum method to do the calculations correctly?

You're still assembling the TCP header length wrong - big endian means the more significant octet is at the end. Just swap pseudoHeaderAndTcpSegment bytes 10 and 11.

That still does not fix the issue

Can you add an example of the packet where the checksum calculation fails? And I assume you verified the checksum is actually correct (e.g. in Wireshark)? :D Don't forget things like checksum offloading exist; the checksum you're capturing isn't necessarily correct.

Is there any program out there that can take a byte array and then output the correct checksum? Also, I looked up checksum offloading, and wire shark can be affected by this as well. What do u get for the following I calculate 9826 while it says 97E0... 45 00 00 6E 5B 7D 40 00 37 06 CC 54 A2 9F 85 EA C0 A8 32 86 01 BB D4 5A 27 3B 46 F8 72 7B 54 D1 50 18 00 05 97 E0 00 00 17 03 03 00 41 5C 07 93 EF 58 B0 BC 23 33 FC 12 3E EA D6 BA 13 37 C3 30 5B E7 F1 A3 55 6F 5C D6 EC 84 D2 7B 4E 5B CF 22 29 C1 24 68 BB 14 B2 C4 D7 1E 10 5F 60 67 A4 E7 EF 6E 89 2B 48 25 BD A9 C2 54 9E 5E 7D BB

@UnSure "Wireshark can be affected by this as well" is exactly the point - if Wireshark can't verify the checksum, it's not a problem in your code - it just means the checksum in the captured packet isn't the actual checksum .

Can you send the actual Ethernet (or at least IP) packet dump instead of the pseudo-header?

Yes, I understand that but how can I verify that my CheckSum calculations are correct instead of just assuming so? Where should I capture the "Ethernet (or at least IP) packet dump"?

@UnSure Just try capturing the packet in Wireshark and getting a full dump, and let Wireshark calculate the checksum to see if it's actually correct - that's what you can compare to your algorithm.

How I turned off Checksum offloading from my network card directly and then used WireShark to verify my checksums and I can in fact confirm they are incorrect. What should I try and do now?

I finally was able to fix it! I just needed to modify a single line to pseudoHeaderAndTcpSegment[11] = (byte)((tcpLength + payloadLength) & 0xFF);
